# Looking for a two step first-order reaction with a useful intermediate

Tags: reaction-mechanism, kinetics

I am working on a mathematical model for my homework, and would like to do some tests to see if it is accurate in real life as well. The model involves a two step chemical reaction in the form of the following:
\begin{align}
\ce{A + B &-> C + D} \tag{1}\\ 
\ce{C + D &-> products} \tag{2}
\end{align}

Is anyone aware of such processes where either $\ce{C}$ and $\ce{D}$ are:

1. measurable (not necessarily continuously, could be done by say, quenching the reaction at intervals);
2. are also useful in real life in some way or another;
3. where the order of reaction with respect to the chemicals are first order?

Any ideas are welcome!